# Pandas dataframe reshape row values into new columns (matrix type format)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I'm new to pandas and was looking for some advice on how to reshape my dataframe:

Currently, I have a dataframe like this.

| panelist_id | type | type_count | refer_sm_count | refer_se_count | refer_non_n_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HP | 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | PB | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | TN | 3 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | HP | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | PB | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Ideally, I want my dataframe to look like this:

| panelist_id | type_HP_count | type_PB_count | type_TN_count | refer_sm_count_HP | refer_se_count_HP | refer_non_n_count_HP | refer_sm_count_PB | refer_se_count_PB | refer_non_n_count_PB | refer_sm_count_TN | refer_se_count_TN | refer_non_n_count_TN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Basically, I need to convert the different row values in the 'type' column into new columns, showing the count for each type. The next three columns on the original df titled 'refer' need to account for each different 'type'. e.g., refers_sm_count_[from type X (e.g., HP)]. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try via `pivot_table()` and `rename_axis()` method:

```
out=(df.pivot_table(index='panelist_id',columns='type',fill_value=0)
      .rename_axis(columns=[None,None],index=None))
```

Finally use `map()` method and `.columns` attribute:

```
out.columns=out.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your desired output

Comment: Thanks Anurag - I get an error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects. Any ideas as how to fix?

Comment: pivot_table can handle this type of problems....what is your pandas version?

Answer (score 3):

A [`pivot_wider`](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_wider.html#janitor.pivot_wider) option via [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/installation.html):

```
new_df = df.pivot_wider(index='panelist_id',
                        names_from='type',
                        names_from_position='last',
                        fill_value=0)
```

`new_df`:

```
panelist_id  type_count_HP  type_count_PB  type_count_TN  refer_sm_count_HP  refer_sm_count_PB  refer_sm_count_TN  refer_se_count_HP  refer_se_count_PB  refer_se_count_TN  refer_non_n_count_HP  refer_non_n_count_PB  refer_non_n_count_TN
          1              2              1              3                  2                  0                  0                  1                  1                  3                     1                     0                     0
          2              1              2              0                  1                  1                  0                  0                  1                  0                     0                     0                     0
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'panelist_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'type': ['HP', 'PB', 'TN', 'HP', 'PB'],
    'type_count': [2, 1, 3, 1, 2],
    'refer_sm_count': [2, 0, 0, 1, 1],
    'refer_se_count': [1, 1, 3, 0, 1],
    'refer_non_n_count': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})

new_df = df.pivot_wider(index='panelist_id',
                        names_from='type',
                        names_from_position='last',
                        fill_value=0)

print(new_df.to_string(index=False))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just adding one more option:

```
df = df.set_index(['panelist_id', 'type']).unstack(-1, ,fill_value=0)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Answer (score 2):

use pivot_table to create a multi-index

```
df_p = df.pivot_table(index='panelist_id', columns='type', aggfunc=sum)

            refer_non_n_count           refer_se_count            \
type                       HP   PB   TN             HP   PB   TN   
panelist_id                                                        
1                         1.0  0.0  0.0            1.0  1.0  3.0   
2                         0.0  0.0  NaN            0.0  1.0  NaN   

            refer_sm_count           type_count            
type                    HP   PB   TN         HP   PB   TN  
panelist_id                                                
1                      2.0  0.0  0.0        2.0  1.0  3.0  
2                      1.0  1.0  NaN        1.0  2.0  NaN
```

if you do want to flatten your columns then

```
df_p.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df_p.columns.values]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This returns me an error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Answer (score 2):

First, import libs:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Then, read your data:

```
data = pd.read_excel('base.xlsx')
```

Reshape your data using pivot_table:

```
data_reshaped = pd.pivot_table(data, values=['type_count', 'refer_sm_count', 'refer_se_count', 'refer_non_n_count'],
                               index=['panelist_id'], columns=['type'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

But, your index will not be good. So, reset then:

```
columns = [data_reshaped.columns[i][0] + '_' + data_reshaped.columns[i][1]
           for i in range(len(data_reshaped.columns))] # to create new columns names

data_reshaped.columns = columns # to assign new columns names to dataframe
data_reshaped.reset_index(inplace=True) # to reset index
data_reshaped.fillna(0, inplace=True) # to substitute nan to 0
```

Then, your data will be like good